# Python: RegEx for getting groups from "day, day, day from hour to min"

Tags: python, regex, find

This is my input strings

```
1. Mon,Tue,Wed from 10AM to 12PM
2. Mon from 10AM to 12PM
3. Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu from 10AM to 12PM
```

I want my groups to be

```
1. ["Mon,Tue,Wed", "10AM","12pm"]
2. ["Mon", "10AM", "12PM"]
3. ["Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu", "10AM", "12PM"]
```

Here the first groups comes with the 3 lettered week days separated by comma,
I am not understanding cleary how to find the RegEx for finding the first group in it.

I tried:

```
(^((mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun|mo|tu|we|th|fr|sa|su|m|w|f),?){1,} # Weekday
\s*[from]*\s* # Seperator
(\d{1,2}(?:[:]\d{1,2})?)\s*([ap][.]?m.?) # Start hour
\s*[-,(to)]+\s* # Seperator
(\d{1,2}(?:[:]\d{1,2})?)\s*([ap][.]?m.?)) # Close hour
```

Comment: It would help if you show what you've attempted so far; someone could then point you in the right direction. Requesting for a solution without showing prior effort is generally frowned upon on [so].

Comment: I tried        (^((mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun|mo|tu|we|th|fr|sa|su|m|w|f),?){1,} # Weekday
        \s*[from]*\s*                                                # Seperator
        (\d{1,2}(?:[:]\d{1,2})?)\s*([ap][.]?m.?)                     # Start hour
        \s*[-,(to)]+\s*                                              # Seperator
        (\d{1,2}(?:[:]\d{1,2})?)\s*([ap][.]?m.?))                    # Close hour

Comment: @flower: update the question with what to tried, rather than in comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meant to be used with `re.findall`. Result captured in the 1st, 2nd and 3rd capturing groups. The later additions are based on the regex you put in the comment.

```
r'(?i)((?:sun|mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat)(?:\s*,\s*(?:sun|mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat))*)\s+from\s+(\d{1,2}(?::\d{1,2})?(?:[ap]m|[ap]\.m\.))(?:\s+to\s+|\s*[-,]\s*)(\d{1,2}(?::\d{1,2})?(?:[ap]m|[ap]\.m\.))'
```

Regex break down:

- Case insensitive

  ```
  (?i)
  ```
- List of days of the week. Allow for flexible spacing. No trailing or extra `,` allowed:

  ```
  ((?:sun|mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat)(?:\s*,\s*(?:sun|mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat))*)
  ```
- There must be at least one space before and after `from`.

  ```
  \s+from\s+
  ```
- Matching number followed by AM/PM (can be `am` or `a.m.`, but not `a.m` or `am.` - same for `pm`). Also allow for minute to be optionally specified.

  ```
  (\d{1,2}(?::\d{1,2})?\s*(?:[ap]m|[ap]\.m\.))
  ```
- I relaxed the condition for `to` part: the to part can be `to`, or `-` or `,`. There must be space before and after `to`, but `-` and `,` doesn't need space to precede/succeed.

  ```
  (?:\s+to\s+|\s*[-,]\s*)
  ```
- Same as above

  ```
  (\d{1,2}(?::\d{1,2})?\s*(?:[ap]m|[ap]\.m\.))
  ```

This approach while splitting the input into tokens, also validates the tokens.

If the validation is unnecessary, you can use splitting like `theharshest` suggested. I would use `re.split` and split by `r'\s+from\s+'` first, then split the 2nd token by `r'\s*(to|[-,])\s*'`.

Comment: I got [('Tue,Wed', '10AM', '12PM')], Mon is missing in first group.

Comment: I can use @theharshest but from wont come always sometimes its just a space sometimes its '-'. So I could go re.split()

Comment: @flower: I have read the intent in your unsuccessful attempt and modify it to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need regex here, just split using keywords 'from' and 'to' -

For first example, if s is your string -

```
>>> s.split('from')[0]
'Mon,Tue,Wed '
>>> s.split('from')[1].split('to')
[' 10AM ', ' 12PM']
```